# What scala domain models for play framework 1.2.2RC1+ looks like when using Casbah?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, casbah

The documentation for [Casbah](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/2.1.5.0/setting_up.html) does not mention play framework.

What is the format of scala domain model for Casbah in Play framework 1.2.2RC1+
and how do I make queries ?

Answer (score 1):

I would say - the same as in Casbah without Play. There's little magic going on between the "C" and "M" parts of Play, so you can just implement your model as you like. Queries you typically trigger from the controller, and in the Scala case, I'd wrap them in domain model companion objects.